# Creating subclass of a class in java

Tags: java

## edited version. I think my question was not clear. So, i have made some changes. I have a package named "module 6". Under module 6, there are two separate classes named "EarthquakeCityMap" and "CommonMarker". Inside the EarthquakeCityMap Class there are declaration for List, Strings. For eg:

```
 public class EarthquakeCityMap {
```

private UnfoldingMap map;

```
private List<Marker> cityMarkers;
private List<Marker> quakeMarkers;
private List<Marker> countryMarkers;
private CommonMarker lastSelected;


   }
```

I understand the declaration "List" but could not understand "private CommonMarker lastSelected"

I do not want to give you trouble. But if you could not understand this, here is the link for the entire source code
https://github.com/areszhao/UnfoldingMaps/tree/master/src/module6

Thank you

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: we can't help you if you don't ask a specific question.

Comment: `private CommonMarker lastSelected;` : Declaring a private `CommonMarker` type variable named `lastSelected`.

Comment: See Docs: [Private visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/134/visibility-controlling-access-to-members-of-a-class/519/private-visibility#t=201608261130301789984)

Comment: @manabreak, op seems to have problems understanding what `private CommonMarker lastSelected;` does, and how it fits together with the class declared as `private abstract class CommonMarker extends SimplePointMarker` which presumably is an inner class.

Comment: @aioobe I disagree. OP has problems doing research before posting a question.

Comment: @ppeterka, your comment doesn't really make sense. I never said OP did *not* have problems doing research before posting a question.

Comment: @aioobe No offense, but if we don't have a bell, it does not matter if it is noon or not, right?

Comment: @ppeterka, uhm, never heard that expression before. Do you mean that if OP don't know how to do proper research first, it doesn't matter whether the question can be understood or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121922/discussion-between-ppeterka-and-aioobe).

Comment: The code you’ve posted doesn’t compile. Is `CommonMarker` declared *inside* `EarthquakeCityMap`? A top-level class cannot be declared `private`.

Comment: @OleV.V., you can probably assume that the `CommonMarker` class is declared inside `EarthQuaceCityMap` (since, as you say, it's `private` and since it is indented).

Comment: @S.Gurung Welcome to StackOverflow. This question leaves out many details. I encourage you to edit the question to sort this out, and also spell out the question you have as precisely as you can. To avoid getting down-votes and close-votes, try to do this from the beginning next time you post a question. Good luck with the coursera course.

Comment: The reason i had difficulty to explain the question is that i did not see such syntax before. I know a bit about inner class where you have classes inside the other class. As i have shown you above, there are two classes in a package. One is an abstract class named CommonMarker and the other is a class named EarthquakeCityMap. There is a declaration inside EarthquakeCityMap as i have shown above- "private CommonMarker lastSelected" I dont know what it means. I hope you get the question. Thanks. Or I can post the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

It means that a `EarthquakeCityMap` class *has a* `CommonMarker` called lastSelected, and that access to the lastSelected object is restricted to within the `EarthquakeCityMap` class.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong (or at best, vague) on multiple causes and also incomplete. I fail to see how it gets upvotes.

Comment: I think it's pretty spot on. We have a silly and trivial question, so it is expected that it gets a somewhat trivial and obvious answer. If OP was also wondering about the `CommonMarker` class declaration, then sure, the answer is incomplete.

Comment: To be more precise, each instance (object) of the `EarthquakeCityMap` has a `CommonMarker`. I upvoted nevertheless.